# String parameter not working in jenkins shell

Tags: json, shell, jenkins

I create a new build with a parametrized string. The name fo the parameter is VERSION.

In the build I have this command:

```
sed -i -e 's/REPLACE_ME/$VERSION/g' config/config.json
```

The json file looks this way:

```
{
"ENV": {
    "name": "test",
    "version": "REPLACE_ME",
}
}
```

What happens is that REPLACE_ME is replaced by $VERSION.
I also tried with ${VERSION} but still no luck.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try your `sed` command with double quotes.

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Comment: Good :) Added answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround your `sed` string with double quotes so that the variable is expanded properly.